# Equation with complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

> Find all $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $\text{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=-i\,\text{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)$.

(Here, I assume, that $\text{Log}\,z=\ln|z|+i\,\text{Arg}\,z$ with $\text{Arg}\,z\in(-\pi,\pi]$.) I did it by modifications of the RHS

$$-i\,\text{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)=-i\,\text{Log}\left(i\left(z-i\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)\right)=-i\left(\text{Log}\,(i)+\text{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\,\text{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$$
which is not correct, but after some tedious computations I found
$$z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
The problem is, that $\bar z$ is also a root, which I lost in the process. So my questions are

1. How to proceed in order to solve the equation without losing anything?
2. Is it possible to simplify the process of solution using the fact that $\text{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)=\text{Argsinh}\,(iz)$ and the LHS is almost $\text{Argcosh}\,(z)$ ?
3. What would change if we replace princial $\text{Log}$ with multi-valued $\log$ in the original equation?

---

Edit2: resolved on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1853214p12513067)

---

Edit: Maybe I should have proceed in this way.
$$-i\,\text{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)=-i\,\text{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{(-1)\left(z^2-1\right)}\right)=-i\,\text{Log}\left(iz\pm i\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=-i\,\left(\text{Log}(i)+\text{Log}\left(z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\,\text{Log}\left(z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$$
Now, focus on the variant with $+$ and I get 
$$z_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\sinh\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
as before. For this particular $z_0$ we have
$$\text{Arg}(-1)=\pi\quad\text{and}\quad\text{Arg}\left(z_0^2-1\right)\approx-1.981\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\sqrt{(-1)\left(z_0^2-1\right)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{z_0^2-1}$$
similarly,
$$\text{Arg}(i)=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad\text{Arg}\left(z_0\pm\sqrt{z_0^2-1}\right)=\mp\frac{\pi}{4}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\text{Log}\left(iz_0\pm i\sqrt{z_0^2-1}\right)=\text{Log}(i)+\text{Log}\left(z_0\pm\sqrt{z_0^2-1}\right)$$
so, the (possibly incorrect) steps above should be now justified. This won't work for $\bar{z_0}$ though, because $\text{Arg}\left(\bar{z_0}^2-1\right)\approx+1.981$, but I believe it could be made by a diffrent choice of $\text{Arg}$, namely for $\text{Arg}\,w\in[-\pi,\pi)$.

But still, I'm missing the other root. [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(z%2Bsqrt(z%5E2-1))%3Dpi%2F2-i*log(z-sqrt(z%5E2-1))) claims that
$$\text{Log}\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\,\text{Log}\left(z-\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)$$
has a root $\approx0.93664 + 0.614243 i$, which numerically corresponds with $\bar{z_0}$. I don't see how to solve this one though...